# runValidator property not working on upsert on mongodb with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My model has a validator function, which checks for the ForeignKey.

Below is my model code for locationId property.

```
locationId: {
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            validate: {
                isAsync: true,
                validator: function(v) {
                    return FKHelper(mongoose.model('Account_LocationMapping'), v);
                },
                message: `LocationId doesn't exist`
            }
          }
```

**FK Helper**

```
module.exports = (model, id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        model.findOne({ _id: id }, (err, result) => {
            if (result) {
                return resolve(true);
            } else
                return reject(
                    new Error(`FK Constraint 'checkObjectsExists' for '${id.toString()}' failed`)
                );
        });
    });
};
```

**My upsert query:**

```
 updateOne: {
               filter: {
                         accountId: req.account
                       },
               update: {
                         $set: { locationId: req.location },
                         //runValidator:true -> tried setting the validator property inside update.
                       },
               upsert: true,
               runValidators: true
            }
```

Both the ways what i tried of setting up the runValidator:true is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is here: `When using update validators, required validators only fail when you try to explicitly $unset the key.`

From the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-only-run-on-updated-paths