# Why does the updateOne doesn't validate according to the schema model, even after setting the runValidators to true?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

Okay, so I am trying to update an array of objects in MongoDB. I have used **updateOne** in this case to update the array of objects.

Here is an example of an array of objects in JSON format which my app sends

```
[
    {
      "_id": 6,
      "todo": "walk"
    },
    {
        "_id":7,
        "todo":"run"
    },{
        "_id":8,
        "todo":"dance"
    }
]
```

Here is my schema

```
const todos = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    todos_list: [
      {
        _id: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
          unique: true,
        },
        todo: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 1, maxlength: 100 },
      },
    ],
    user_id: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { collection: "user.todosList" }
);
```

Here is the code for finding the document on the basis of user_id and updating it.

```
const { token, todos_list } = req.body;
  try {
    const userData = verifyToken(token);
    const user_id = userData.id;

    const query = await todoSchema.updateOne(
      { user_id },
      { $addToSet: { todos_list } },
      { runValidators: true }
    );
    res.send({ status: "ok", query });
  } catch (err) {
    res.send({ status: "error", err });
  }
```

When I run this code for the first time, it runs perfectly. But the problem comes when I update my **todo** value to something else.

For example, let's say that I want to update my todo at **id:7**. Right now the current value of my current todo is **run**. And if I change it to **run at 5 p.m.**. What the code will do is add another object at the end of my **todo_list** array. The **runValidators** are of no use and doesn't check for the duplicate **_id** in my document.

Comment: Try to use this options too `{ new:true, runValidators: true, upsert: true }`

Comment: Don't forget to add a `{new: true}` option, which returns the updated document back to your project variable.

Comment: Possibly duplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315009/runvalidator-property-not-working-on-upsert-on-mongodb-with-mongoose)